# how to check if a substring exist

Tags: shell, ash

I have the following string

```
msg="bbb. aaa.ccc. bbb.dddd. aaa.eee."
```

the separator between the sub strings is the **space**.

I want to check for example if `"aaa.`" exist. in the above msg it does not exist.

I want to check for example if  `"bbb.`" exist. in the above msg it exists.

I tried with grep, but grep works with newlines as the separators between substrings

How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in bash using pattern matching. You want to check if

- the substring is at the start of the string
- the substring is in the middle, or
- the substring is at the end

```
# pass the string, the substring, and the word separator
matches() {
    [[ $1 == $2$3* ]] || [[ $1 == *$3$2$3* ]] || [[ $1 == *$3$2 ]]
}
msg="bbb. aaa.ccc. bbb.dddd. aaa.eee."
matches "$msg" "aaa." " " && echo y || echo n
matches "$msg" "bbb." " " && echo y || echo n
```

```
n
y
```

---

This works with [dash](/questions/tagged/dash), so it should work with ash too:

```
str_contains_word() {
    sep=${3:-" "}
    case "$1" in
        "$2$sep"* | *"$sep$2$sep"* | *"$sep$2") return 0;;
        *) return 1;;
    esac
}

msg="bbb. aaa.ccc. bbb.dddd. aaa.eee."
for substr in aaa. bbb.; do
    printf "%s: " "$substr"
    if str_contains_word "$msg" "$substr"; then echo yes; else echo no; fi
done
```

Comment: I don't know if [tag:ash] does pattern matching the same way within double brackets.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use the `-w` option with `grep`, which would prevent `aaa.` from matching `aaa.ccc`.

```
if fgrep -qw 'aaa.' <<< "$msg"; then
    # Found aaa.
else:
    # Did not find aaa.
fi
```

Comment: You need to escape the dot.

Comment: Oops, I think I intended to use `fgrep` and forgot.

Comment: my ash does not support fgrep

Comment: How about `grep -F`? (`fgrep` is typically just a synonym for that option, so you may not have it either). Note that `grep` is a separate program, so the options it supports are independent of which shell you are using (but very dependent on what version of `grep` is installed on your system).